# Web App deployment failure in Azure - "Virtual network associated with the link cannot be changed"

Tags: python, postgresql, azure

Whilst trying to deploy a Web App + Database in Azure I'm getting the deployment error message below. I've tried looking up the message "Virtual network associated with the link cannot be changed" but can't make much sense of what to do next, or why the deployment might have failed.

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "Conflict",
                "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n        \"message\": \"Virtual network associated with the link cannot be changed.\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the past I've deployed the same service within this resource group (and still have it running), and it's worked fine. I followed the exact same steps as before but I'm now getting consistent failures.

Comment: What is the framework and version of the Web App ? And which DB?

Comment: Its running Python 3.9 and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way too late for the topic opener but hopefully this helps someone else. I was running into this same problem. Trying it again with a new resource group fixed it.